# Azure Data factory: How to update the pipeline parameter (flag) inside the pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have initialized a pipeline parameter, lets say a flag, with a value ('true'). Now inside the pipeline I want to update the flag value based on some condition.

So lets say I have a web activity inside the pipeline, I want to update the value of that flag to 'false' if i dont get the response from the web activity.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try @empty(body('web1'))

Comment: Thanks @Fang I was not aware that ADFv2 uses expressions of logic apps. Although I have commented on the other post about how to update the pipeline parameter inside of the pipeline. Please do have a look.

Comment: Originally, I am thinking you want to update the until condition. But now I got your point. You want to update the url of web activity. Let me think it over.

Comment: Sure. I have been waiting for your reply since last 18 hours. :(

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly you want to call a Web activity from your pipeline and if there is no response then set a variable?

In this case, could you not just set a low timeout and use a "Set Variable" activity on the Fail condition? So if there was no response it would fail and set the variable